# Im looking for a simulator that i can use to test my smpp 3.4 client

Tags: client, simulator, smpp

Im looking for a simulator that i can use to test my smpp 3.4 client that sends sms via network operator to their smsc that i have developed with nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your own, [this](https://melroselabs.com/services/smsc-simulator/) is one I used to use and was very helpful.

Comment: i want to test my smpp from localhost , is it possible with them thanks in advance

Comment: Thankyou sir i am now able to test my smpp 3.4 client using that link you provided thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, recently me too had such question, but I found already made solution. [This one](https://maxisms-simulator.com/) is a really good. For me it was easy to strat using